# How to set environment variables for a Gnome Wayland session

Tags: arch-linux, environment-variables, gnome3, gdm, wayland

It seems that a [Gnome Wayland](https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/Wayland) session ignores the file `~/.profile`. At least it is not working for me under a Gdm / Gnome / wayland session with Arch Linux.

So the question is, what is the  proper user file to use for environment variables for a `gnome-wayland` session? Does Wayland even support those kind of settings?

Comment: Try [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175971/setting-environment-variables-for-gnome-on-wayland-session-only).

Comment: gnome-wayland session ignores my ~/.profile file. But , the gnome-x11 session works fine with that file.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I have the same issue. It's vaguely mentioned [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/Wayland/SessionStart).

Answer (score 7):

Systemd version 233 (March 2017) added support for setting environment variables in `~/.config/environment.d/*.conf`. See [the `environment.d` man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/environment.d.html) and the discussion that led to the feature on [this preliminary PR](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/3904) and [this final one](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/5131).

Also discussed here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403196/23305

Answer (score 2):

A way that works for me is using `~/.pam_environment`.

Use `man pam_env.conf` for reference.

I just need some user paths added to `PATH` in a GNOME/Wayland session and added the following line to `~/.pam_environment`.

```
PATH        OVERRIDE=${HOME}/bin:${HOME}/.local/bin:${PATH}
```

Comment: this does not work in wayland.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in Wayland yet.

Dot files like .pam_environment, .profile, and obviously .xinitrc are ignored.

The closest way to do this would be to add a line like below to the bottom of your ~/.bashrc file (assuming you're using bash) and then setting your terminal emulator to launch on startup.

```
[[ $ENVSETUP != 0 ]] && export ENVSETUP=0 && exit
```

This would make your terminal open when you login, but immediately close. Then all your environment variables defined in the .bashrc would be set-up.

Comment: This is outdated, see the other answers.